# Registering a ContentObserver in AppWidgetProvider to update AppWidget is not working

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-appwidget, contentobserver, appwidgetprovider

I have a `ContentProvider` from a main app. The content will be shared with a consumer app. This consumer app has an app widget. I have tested the `ContentProvider` and `ContentObserver` to this consumer app in its Activity and all is well (meaning the `RecyclerView` of the Activity is updated whenever an update from the main app triggers changes to the database). However, registering the `ContentObserver` inside my `AppWidgetProvider` does not work as expected.

My `AppWidgetProvider` has the following code.

```
class StackWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        Timber.i("Enabled")
        if (favoriteUserProviderObserver == null) {
            val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
            val componentName = ComponentName(context, StackWidgetProvider::class.java)
            favoriteUserProviderObserver = FavoriteUserProviderObserver(appWidgetManager, componentName).let {
                context.contentResolver.registerContentObserver(CONTENT_URI, true, it)
                it
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        Timber.i("Disabled")
        favoriteUserProviderObserver?.let {
            context.contentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(it)
        }
        favoriteUserProviderObserver = null
    }

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }
    ....

    companion object {
        private var favoriteUserProviderObserver: FavoriteUserProviderObserver? = null

        private fun updateAppWidget(
            context: Context,
            appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
            appWidgetId: Int
        ) {
            val intent = Intent(context, StackWidgetService::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
                data = toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME).toUri()
            }

            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_favorite_user_stack).apply {
                setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_favorite_user_stack_view, intent)
                setEmptyView(R.id.widget_favorite_user_stack_view, R.id.widget_favorite_user_empty)
            }

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }
    }
}
```

I created a simple custom `ContentObserver` class like below.

```
class FavoriteUserProviderObserver(
    private val appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    private val componentName: ComponentName
) : ContentObserver(null) {
    override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
        Timber.i("Provider observer triggered")
        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(
            appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName), R.id.widget_favorite_user_stack_view
        )
    }
}
```

The above observer class is never triggered (even when I change the data in my main app). For further clarity, here's the code for my `RemoteViewsService` and its factory.

```
class StackWidgetService : RemoteViewsService() {
    override fun onGetViewFactory(intent: Intent): RemoteViewsFactory =
        StackRemoteViewsFactory(this.applicationContext)
}

class StackRemoteViewsFactory(private val context: Context) :
    RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
    private var widgetItems = listOf<UserProfileSummary>()
    private lateinit var repository: FavoriteUserRepository

    override fun onCreate() {
        repository = FavoriteUserRepository(
            FavoriteUserDataSource(context.contentResolver),
            Dispatchers.IO
        )
    }

    override fun onDataSetChanged() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            widgetItems = repository.favoriteUsers().toList() // Tested; working on the Activity scope of the consumer app
            Timber.i(widgetItems.toString())
        }
    }

    override fun getViewAt(position: Int): RemoteViews =
        RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_favorite_user_item).apply {
            setTextViewText(R.id.widget_favorite_user_item_text, widgetItems[position].username)
        }

    override fun getLoadingView(): RemoteViews? = null

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = 0

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean = false

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return widgetItems.size
    }

    override fun getViewTypeCount(): Int = 1

    override fun onDestroy() {}
}
```

So the logic is to ask the `ContentObserver` to observe changes in the `ContentProvider`. The observer is registered on the `onEnabled` and `onDisabled` part of the `AppWidgetProvider`. Once the observer notices a change in `ContentProvider`, it will ask the `AppWidgetProvider` to update itself, thus calling `onDataSetChanged` and fetching a new list of data.

However, the observer is never called. What could be the reason it's not working as expected here? (It can't be because of a lack of permission, because the Activity part of the consumer app is able to fetch the data just fine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be the reason it's not working as expected here?

An `AppWidgetProvider` is a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`. Your instance of `AppWidgetProvider` will live for (hopefully) a very short time, best measured in milliseconds. Basically, you get one `onUpdate()` call (or other callback), and that instance is thrown away. The next callback gets a new instance.

As a result, doing anything in an `AppWidgetProvider` that requires it to be around for a period of time is doomed.

The most likely solution, taking modern versions of Android into account, is to adopt more of a push solution. Bear in mind that any of your code can update the `RemoteViews` for an app widget, simply by working with `AppWidgetManager`. So, some code that is already running and knows about the data updates needs to push a new `RemoteViews`, rather than expecting your `AppWidgetProvider` to be able to react to changes.

Comment: What does *a push solution* mean? Do you have a link to a sample?

Comment: @Richard: "What does a push solution mean?" -- see the last sentence. Basically, you get an `AppWidgetManager` and call `updateAppWidget()` outside of the `AppWidgetProvider`, at the point when the data changes. IOW, you are pushing `RemoteViews` changes to the `AppWidgetManager` when the data changes, rather than expecting your `AppWidgetProvider` to react to changes.

Comment: @Richard: "Do you have a link to a sample?" -- no, sorry. I have app widget samples, but they are old and do not demonstrate this particular approach. However, particularly since Apple's recent updates are giving new interest to app widgets, I should write some new samples and hopefully will get to that over the next few months. I'll specifically try to handle this scenario, as it is more relevant now.

Comment: I see. Please correct me if I'm wrong: I think that you're suggesting utilizing my existing observer in **consumer app**'s activity to also call `updateAppWidget` (aside from updating the Activity's `RecyclerView`); is this it? If it is, what if my consumer app is also not running when the data change in my ContentProvider happens? In other words, I'm not really sure at which part of my consumer app's code I should register a long-lived observer to call the `updateAppWidget` method. Perhaps launching a long-lived "task/thread" that exceeds the lifespan of my consumer app?

Comment: @Richard: "utilizing my existing observer in consumer app's activity to also call updateAppWidget(); is this it?" -- probably not, for the reasons you mentioned. "I'm not really sure at which part of my consumer app's code I should register a long-lived observer" -- to be honest, your setup is awkward. If your `minSdkVersion` is 24 or higher, [use `JobScheduler` and `addTriggerContentUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder?hl=en#addTriggerContentUri(android.app.job.JobInfo.TriggerContentUri)) to get background control when the provider changes.

Comment: @Richard: If your `minSdkVersion` is older than that, for those older devices, you would need to try to have an always-running `Service` that has your `ContentObserver`. This is far from ideal, which is why newer versions of Android all but ban the practice. Another possibility is to have your main app also send a broadcast or something when the data changes, so you can listen for that and elect to update the app widget at that point.

Comment: I see. Okay, I also thought of using a `Service`, but it seems like an overkill. I also stumbled on `JobScheduler` and said `addTriggerContentUri` earlier today, but I am currently learning and my course doesn't really mention anything about using a `JobScheduler` to monitor a `ContentProvider`. Nevertheless, thanks! I will try to change my code to implement `JobScheduler` instead; but if you have time, do update the answer to include a sample you're going to work on. (Although I do like the idea of the main app sending a broadcast too.)

Comment: @Richard: "I am currently learning and my course didn't really mention anything about using a `JobScheduler` to monitor a `ContentProvider`" -- `JobScheduler` originally did not have that feature; they added it later. [This older sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/JobScheduler/Content) (profiled in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android)) demonstrates its use, though not in the area of app widgets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219443/discussion-between-richard-and-commonsware).